# zipping files from another server and serving to clients in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I'm trying to make an application which will get multiple links for download from another server, zip them up on my server and forward the zip to the client. So I have a few questions:

1) how do these online YouTube/video downloaders work? Do they download all files for you and then serve a link for the file? If so, then how do they deal with storage space? Or do they directly stream the files? How does this process work?

2) let's say I have a middle server which queries another server for the file links (via Ajax call), then gets the link. Now should i download all these files on my disk, zip then and then send to client? Or is there some way i zip the files on the fly and send a stream (i am not aware of how streams work) to the client?

Thanks!

Comment: For downloading streams usually people use youtube-dl or ffmpeg. Here is an npm package for youtube-dl: https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core
When you are downloading the file you actually save it on you local storage, then manipulate it (you can zip some files together) and then send it to the client 
For sending files in a response look here : https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download
You also need to manage local storage and remove old files

Comment: so all these video downloading websites, they actually download the videos first and then serve to the client? Wouldn't that mean a lot of storage cost?

Comment: They have to save in order to change the stream to selected format. They just remove the file after sending it to you (or on a scheduled operation)